# "The connection attempt failed" Postgres at AWS Lambda

Tags: java, postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I have a Postgres DB on AWS that is available outside. The connection works fine when I launch my app locally.

When I launch it on AWS lambda it gives me this error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:292)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:195)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:454)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:256)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
    at ninja.majewski.AmazonDbService.getRemoteConnection(AmazonDbService.java:84)
    at ninja.majewski.AmazonDbService.removeOldDeals(AmazonDbService.java:63)
    at ninja.majewski.ChinaStuffLambdaHandler.handleRequest(ChinaStuffLambdaHandler.java:19)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at lambdainternal.EventHandlerLoader$PojoMethodRequestHandler.handleRequest(EventHandlerLoader.java:259)
    at lambdainternal.EventHandlerLoader$PojoHandlerAsStreamHandler.handleRequest(EventHandlerLoader.java:178)
    at lambdainternal.EventHandlerLoader$2.call(EventHandlerLoader.java:888)
    at lambdainternal.AWSLambda.startRuntime(AWSLambda.java:292)
    at lambdainternal.AWSLambda.<clinit>(AWSLambda.java:64)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at lambdainternal.LambdaRTEn
    try.main(LambdaRTEntry.java:94)
```

This is the code that fails:

```
private Connection getRemoteConnection() throws Exception {
    Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    String dbName = System.getenv("RDS_DB_NAME");
    String userName = System.getenv("RDS_USERNAME");
    String password = System.getenv("RDS_PASSWORD");
    String hostname = System.getenv("RDS_HOSTNAME");
    String port = System.getenv("RDS_PORT");
    String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:postgresql://" + hostname + ":" + port + "/" + dbName + "?user=" + userName + "&password=" + password;
    log.info(String.format("Logging to DB: %s", jdbcUrl));
    return DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl);
}
```

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Is your Lambda function running inside a VPC?

Comment: No. it is not inside VPC

Comment: Is `RDS_HOSTNAME` set? Try to print it out, it could be null, the error shows that there is no suitable database host.

Comment: I print `jdbcUrl` variable and it is correct. If I copy it to IntelliJ it connects to DB correctly. All of these env variables are set

Comment: Is your RDS publicly accesible? If not, did you [configured your lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/vpc.html) so it can access it?

Comment: RDS is accessible publicly.

Comment: Does your Lambda's execution role allow your function to access RDS?

Comment: Yes. It has `AmazonRDSFullAccess` policy

Comment: I'm not sure if it's any different for RDS, but in Redshift, your JDBC URL can start with `jdbc:redshift:iam://` instead of `jdbc:redshift://`. Can you try changing the beginning of your JDBC URL to `jdbc:postgresql:iam://`?

Comment: @JacobG. Now I get this error: `Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.`

Comment: It looks like you're making progress. If your connection is refused, your database must not be accepting connections from your Lambda function for some reason. I'd look your database settings in that case.

Answer (score 1):

In your lambda you have to configurate the `Network` parameter. You have to add a `VPC` and a `Security Group`.

Once this Security Group is added to your lambda, you go to your ***EC2 Management Console*** in ***NETWORK & SECURITY -> Security Groups***. Here you select the Security Group of your RDS Instance and you Edit the `Inbound` parameter. You add a `Type` PostgreSQL with a `Custom Source` with the name of the Security Group you just added to your Lambda.